# node-pre-gyp: not found --fallback to build error while installing bcrypt

Tags: node.js, npm

I am building new node project. while installing `bcrypt` package i got error given below:

```
> bcrypt@5.0.1 install /media/keval/E: Drive/projects/MERN Projects/FMS/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: not found
npm WARN ims@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/keval/.npm/_logs/2021-05-29T09_24_30_366Z-debug.log
```

all other packages are installed properly without error but i got error while installing `bcrypt` only.

i have installed node-pre-gyp.
i found one solution on this problem

```
npm uninstall bcrypt --save
npm install bcrypt@5 --save
```

but this is not working at all.
what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I also faced this problem, but don't worry you can install `bcryptjs` instead of `bcrypt`.
It will work as same as `bcrypt`.
First of all, run this: `npm uninstall bcrypt`
then  `npm install bcryptjs`. It will fix your issue.
But make sure you change the import package like this:
`import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';`